# Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() plugin issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I updated WordPress to the latest version 3.6 and i got this warning in regards to the wpdb::prepare().

It is an issue with the theme's plugin for sliders. I don't know how to edit $wpdb->prepare on this file to make it work with the new WP version.

```
   <?php            $item_count = 0;                        foreach ($sliders as $key => $slider){                                  $cur_slider_id = $key+1;                $item_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(c_id) FROM ". $item_table ." WHERE s_id = '". $cur_slider_id ."'"));              ?>


$count_filter = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM ". $item_table ." WHERE c_id REGEXP '(^".$d.",)|(,".$d."$)|(,".$d.",)|^".$d."$'")); 


$item_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(c_id) FROM ". $item_table ." WHERE c_id RLIKE '^".$h."$' OR c_id RLIKE ',".$h."$' OR c_id RLIKE '^".$h.",' OR c_id RLIKE ',".$h.",' " ));
```

I have these 3 lines that contain the $wpdb->prepare(), please help on how to change this to the way that WP 3.6 accept it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is $item_table defined? Maybe print it to make sure it's got what you want.

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /Library/WebServer/Documents/name/wordpress/wp-content/themes/fringetech/fringe_tech_framework/libs/global/slider_manager.php on line 1 and defined in /Library/WebServer/Documents/name/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 992

Comment: haha no I mean make sure those two vaiables are data that can actually be part of the query. They may be broken before your prepare statement.
Also see this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955416/warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdbprepare?rq=1 I believe its exactly what's happening to your plugin.

Make sure to mark an answer once your all set!

Comment: I don't know for sure about these variables, I don't use that plugin and it is part of the theme. I added null as a second argument to the function and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Awesome work just like that other guy during the 3.5 upgrade. Wanna make mine the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was very happy when I past this code in my wp-config.php file. Warning message was not display again.

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "null" as a second argument to the function fixes the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `wpdb->prepare()` function in a wrong way. Read http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/ to find out how to fix it properly.